# How can I add collisions to Trail Renderer? 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a bullet and the trailrenderer following it. I want to add collision to this Trail Renderer.

created something like a laser beam. It has an invisible bullet at its tip. My problem is that I can't add collisions to the trail renderer that follows it.

My bullet shape its a circle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, I think you should provide more information for your question

Comment: You can add an [EdgeCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EdgeCollider2D.html) and have a script update the edge points. Depending on how complex your beam is you might have to add additional points.

Comment: I made this but now my bullet phsisc dont working corretctly.